# DirectShow raw data access

Tags: directshow, raw-data

How do you access the raw data of a sound file after using DirectShow to load it?

What *interface* allows you to access the raw data of a waveform, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IMediaSample::GetPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407001(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: This is how to get at the data in the actual sample; if you want it available outside of the directshow framework, Dee Mon's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the Sample Grabber filter between file parser and audio card (or other renderer) and query ISampleGrabber interface. It will give you the data as it's passing through.